How to match or blend texture on wall spot repairs?
I'm doing some patches to my home before I list it up for sale. Almost every wall has a slight textured finish to it. , 
I spackled over holes and stuff that were left behind from where we had things hanging, and I need to sand those down a bit, but what's the best way to match that surface texture? Is that kind of texture from a type of paint roller, or should I consider getting those wall texture sprays to try and do spot-blending?

This is an Orange Peel texture.
Sand the edges down so that they blend in to the surroundings.
Cover the floor to protect from overspray.
Use a not inexpensive texture spray, stand about three feet away and with a shaking motion (to randomize the pattern),lightly cover the area and feather out to blend in. Let dry, confirm the results, repeat if necessary.
Prime the treated areas and paint the entire wall.

Depending on what you used for the patch, you might be able to “sand” the edges to a thin transition with a very slightly damp sponge.
